# How to show that a logical argument is valid?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

How to show that this argument is valid?

$(\exists x) [p(x) \to q(x)] \to [(\forall x) p(x) \to (\exists x) q(x)]$

---

I started by showing that $\exists$x [p(x) $\to$ q(x)] is the premise.  But I don't know how to use the laws of logic (Modus Ponens, etc) to set this up.  The only hint I have is step 2 is "existential instantiation", yet that word was not mentioned in that class.

Comment: There are many ways to do that, starting from different definitions and axioms. If you're doing it for a class, you're probably supposed to argue in a specific style that has been taught in that class, and then you need to tell what that style is (or give an example) when you ask the question. For example, what is your definition of "valid"?

Comment: See this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1316828/confusion-about-2-first-order-logic-wffs-they-seem-not-equal-but-instructor) for a "semantical" argument.

Comment: If what you want is an [axiomatic proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system) of it, it will get a little bit tricky, because you premise is a negative statement, i.e. $\neg \forall x \neg (p(x) \rightarrow q(x))$ and the usual axiomatization of first-order logic have [very few](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) to say about them. PS: In the way you posted it, your "argument" is, strictly speaking, a sentence - although, by the deduction theorem, both are in a certain way "equivalent" too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can prove it with *Natural Deduction* :

1) $∃x [p(x) → q(x)]$ --- premise [a]

2) $∀x p(x)$ --- premise [b]

3) $p(a) \to q(a)$ --- assumed [c] for $\exists$-elimination [in *Natural Deduction* this rule replace [Existential instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_instantiation)]

4) $p(a)$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-elimiantion [i.e. [Universal instantiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation)]

5) $q(a)$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\to$-elimination [i.e. *Modus ponens*]

6) $\exists x q(x)$ --- from 5) by $\exists$-introduction followed by $\exists$-elimination from 1) and 3), discharging temporary assumption [c]

7) $∀x p(x) → ∃x q(x)$ --- from 2) and 6) by $\to$-introduction, discharging premise [b] [i.e. [Deduction theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deduction_theorem)]

> $∃x [p(x) → q(x)] \to [∀x p(x) → ∃x q(x)]$ --- from 1) and 7) by $\to$-introduction, discharging premise [a].